# How to change pixel colors for CGImage created from CVPixelBuffer?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple function that gets CVPixelBuffer, turns it into CGImage and assign to the CALayer displayed on the screen.

```
func processResults(_ results: [Any]){
    if let observation = (results as? [VNPixelBufferObservation])?.first {
        var cgImage: CGImage?
        VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(observation.pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)
        caLayer.contents = cgImage
        if caLayer.superlayer == nil {
            segmentationOverlay.addSublayer(caLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

How do I get it?

```
lazy var request: VNCoreMLRequest = {
    let model = try! VNCoreMLModel(for: espnetv2_fp16_new().model)
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { request, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let results = request.results {
                self.processResults(results)
            }
        }
    }
    request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFill
    return request
}()

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:])
        try! handler.perform([request])
    }
}
```

I would like to make the black color totally transparent, and gray one change to green one. Is it possible?

Comment: Does your video capture work without Vision post-processing?

Comment: no, I think... it doesnt...

Comment: well, I did something similar, it’s quite a lot of code. your _captureOutput_ function should be configured to render stuff on AVFoundation’s CALayer. only then should you add some func which uses Vision for some object detection. only then should you add post-filtering those results to receive semitransparent image with green pixels.

Comment: could you post your solution here or via email?

Comment: unfortunately, it’s hard to see which stage is broken in your code snippets. try to extract the problem to get better results.

Comment: https://github.com/gatamar/PhotoApp - this is something similar, but very simple

Comment: If you wish I can share repository with you